# Add variables in specific section during link time

Tags: linker, embedded

Consider the following situation:

- Variables X and Y are part of a library, let us call it lib.o. We do not have the possibility to adapt the corresponding source code of the library (e.g. like adding pragmas)
- X has to be linked to another section than Y, both are currently defined in the same section

Is it possible (in general) for the linker to link individual variables out of a library to a specific (possibly new) section?

The reasoning behind this question is that the library has a buffer overflow bug (memclr with to small buffer (variable X)) and overwrites variable Y. A temporary workaround (until the library will be fixed by the seller) would be to link variable X to a section and leave some space behind, so memclr would not harm important variables.

Comment: Most compilers have *pragmas* or *attributes* that can put variables in different segments. A bigger question (for us) is *why* you want to do it? What is the *actual* problem you try to solve by doing it? Please read [about the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Thanks for your comment, i will edit my post and add the reasoning behind the question. As far as I remember pragmas (or attributes) are mainly interpreted by the compiler, but not by the linker. This is not possible here, since the library is already compiled and therefore, it is not possible to add pragmas or similar stuff

Comment: The sections set by the compiler are part of the object files created by it, and depending on linker it might honor those and pass those on to the final executable file. Otherwise the section attributes/pragmas would be worthless.

Comment: What do you mean with "section" and why do you want to do this?

Comment: Compiler is requesting to place a variable into the specified section, but the linker needs to create this section, and you instruct it to do it in the linker script.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Depending on compiler and linker it can be done automatically. MSVC++ have some support for it IIRC. I don't know about the GCC or Clang stacks.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Perhaps. But I guess in the OP's use case it is of their interest to define the specific section explicitly (it's location and size)

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler is GCC, and,
you have access to the linker script, you can actually force an entire object (or specific sections from it) to a specific area, something like this:

`SECTIONS
{

    custom_sec :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        //custom_object.o
        //custom_object.o (.data)
        //custom_object.o (.bss)
    }
}`

Consult the linker manual. Usually this feature is present in most linkers.